# JS Массивы. Поиск правильной комбинации, которая будет давать, нужный результат, при сложении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Предположительно есть 10 массивов, 4-ре из них участвуют в расчёте (обычное сложение элементов одного массива с другим), результат расчёта записываем в 11-й массив, сравниваем 11-й массив с 12-м с погрешностью +/- 1, если он не удолетворяет условию, просчитать следующую комбинацию.
Если был найден результат, отобразить этот массив и его элементы в консоли, если нет, то сообщаем об этом. Как правильно написать?

```
// МАССИВЫ для расчёта
const arrayOne  = [12, 10, 11, 14,];
const arrayTwo  = [11, 9, 8, 6,];
const arrayThree  = [5, 4, 3, 10,];
const arrayFour  = [10, 8, 2, 4,];
const arrayFive  = [8, 10, 12, 10,];
const arraySix  = [11, 10, 6, 8,];
const arraySeven  = [10, 12, 14, 14,];
const arrayEight  = [8, 10, 15, 15,];
const arrayNine  = [9, 11, 12, 20,];
const arrayTen  = [18, 18, 19, 21,];

let arrayCalc = 4; // число массивов участвующих в расчёта (т.е. это любые массивы из предложенных, а не первые 4)
let arrResult = []; // 11-й массив
```

Цикл сложения элементов массивов, но нужно сделать так, чтобы количество массивов участвующих в сложении, зависело от значения в переменной arrayCalc. Т.е. соответственно если результат не удолетворяет условию, нужно подставлять другие комбинации.

```
for (i=0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) { 
    arrResult.push(arrayOne[i]+arrayTwo[i]+arrayThree[i]+arrayFour[i]+arrayFive[i]+arraySix[i]+arraySeven[i]+arrayEight[i]+arrayNine[i]+arrayTen[i]); 
}
```

Цель заключается в поиске правильной комбинации, которая будет давать нужный результат.

Функция сравнения двух массивов с погрешностью +/- 1:

```
const wishArray = [35, 40, 52, 41]; // 12-й массив с которым сравниваем
function arraySrPart() { 
    const a = arrResult; //11-й
    const b = wishArray; //12-й
    let resultArray = a.every((v,idx) => Math.abs(v - b[idx]) <= 1) ? a : null;
    console.log(resultArray);
}
arraySrPart();
```

Т.е. полагаю должно быть, что-то вроде если resultArray = null, то продолжить поиск правильной комбинации, до тех пор пока не будет найден удовлетворительный результат. Возможно есть способы и получше.

Comment: Слово "расчет" пишется с одним "с".

Comment: и полага́ю заодно

Comment: а по сути? сложно реализуемо?

Comment: я так понимаю, что надо выбирать комбинации по N масивов  из 10 и считать суммы? это основная ваша задача, с как сложить и проверить с желамой это вообще сложности не представляет. хотя, конечно, техническая реализация в приведенном коде так себе

Comment: Да, получается в переменной arrayCalc сейчас стоит значение 4, (оно может меняться), значит в нахождении результата участвует 4 массива из 10, т.е. Массив 1+2+3+4, получили результат проверили его с желаемым результатом, если не сходится, идём дальше 2+3+4+5, проверяем, если не сходится продолжаем дальше, 1+3+5+10 и так далее, т.е. проверяем разные возможные комбинации. Уже думал, может через метки сделать и многомерный массив.. смотрю, пробую варианты, но получаю не то что нужно.

Comment: Такое чувство, что я незнаю какого-то метода. Или что-то упускаю...

Comment: вам нужно генерировать комбинации длины N из 10 элементов. это в целом классический тип комбинаторных задач. Попробуйте тут например посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683091/223826 Это будет генерация индексов для используемых массивов.

Comment: спасибо, данный алгоритм комбинаций мне помог